# Excel Combination Generator

Tags: excel, vba, overflow, permutation, type-mismatch

i have a code that generates a permutation based on the inputs of 8 columns and concatenates the columns together. it works great so far but i came up with a problem. it works when more than 2 rows are filled. so if theres only one entry in row 10 for any of the columns from A-H it crashes. the rows are filled with A,B,C across all 8 columns, if column 8 only had A then it crashes

I've also tried

```
Set col1 = Range(Range("A10"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

instead of

```
Set col1 = Range("A10", Range("A10").End(xlDown))
```

but then there's a type mismatch error.

Any help would be great. This is the whole code:

```
Sub combinations()

Dim out() As Variant
Dim f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m As Long

Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range
Dim col6 As Range
Dim col7 As Range
Dim col8 As Range
Dim out1 As Range

'Set col1 = Range("A10", Range("A10").End(xlDown))
Set col1 = Range(Range("A10"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set col2 = Range("B10", Range("B10").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C10", Range("C10").End(xlDown))
Set col4 = Range("D10", Range("D10").End(xlDown))
Set col5 = Range("E10", Range("E10").End(xlDown))
Set col6 = Range("F10", Range("F10").End(xlDown))
Set col7 = Range("G10", Range("G10").End(xlDown))
Set col8 = Range("H10", Range("H10").End(xlDown))

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3
c4 = col4
c5 = col5
c6 = col6
c7 = col7
c8 = col8

'initializes each column from column1-column8 as Range, sets the size of the range from row10 to last row

Set out1 = Range("M1", Range("T1").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)))
out = out1

'creates a range for the output

f = 1
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1
n = 1

Do While f <= UBound(c1)

    Do While g <= UBound(c2)
        Do While h <= UBound(c3)
            Do While i <= UBound(c4)

    Do While j <= UBound(c5)
        Do While k <= UBound(c6)
            Do While l <= UBound(c7)
             Do While m <= UBound(c8)
            out(n, 1) = c1(f, 1)
            out(n, 2) = c2(g, 1)
            out(n, 3) = c3(h, 1)
            out(n, 4) = c4(i, 1)
            out(n, 5) = c1(j, 1)
            out(n, 6) = c2(k, 1)
            out(n, 7) = c3(l, 1)
            out(n, 8) = c4(m, 1)
            'goes down one column and grabs each cells value

            n = n + 1
            m = m + 1
        Loop
        m = 1
        l = l + 1
    Loop
    l = 1
    k = k + 1
Loop
k = 1
j = j + 1
 Loop
        j = 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 1
    h = h + 1
Loop
h = 1
g = g + 1
Loop
g = 1
f = f + 1
Loop

'repeats process for all 8 columns

out1.Value = out

'places values in the output range "out1"


Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

  'Range("Z1:Z" & LastRow).Formula = "=M1 & "" | "" & N1 & "" | "" & O1 & "" | "" & P1 & "" | "" & Q1 & "" | "" & R1 & "" | "" & S1 & "" | "" & T1 "


  Range("Z1:Z" & LastRow).Formula = "=M1 & $F$3 & N1 & $F$3 & O1 & $F$3 & P1 & $F$3 & Q1 & $F$3 & R1 & $F$3 & S1 & $F$3 & T1 "


     'concatentates the cells from column M-T, seperated by the delimiter in cell F3


    Range("Z1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 120
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

    'Copies the concatenated output, pastes in sheet2 as values

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by crash?  If it produces an error, what is the error message and on what line does it occur.  One problem I see in your scenario is that if you are equating a variant variable to a single-cell range, the resultant variable will **NOT** be an array.  So when you treat it as an array, you will get an error.  You need to check for that in your code.

Comment: Set out1 = Range("M1", Range("T1").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)))   This line results in an overflow error when any of the 8 columns has only one row filled.

Comment: You have several problems then.  If you look at the size of the variant variables, where you only have a single entry, and you are selecting the range with xldown, will result in a huge array.  Check out the locals window and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

```
Set col1 = Range("A10", Range("A10").End(xlDown))
c1 = col1
```

If col1 only has row 10 populated, this sequence results in c1 being a variant array with dimensions (1 to 1048567, 1 to 1)

Better would be:

```
Set col1 = Range("A10", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

but, with that, and only a single cell populated in a column, c1 will no longer be an Array.

So, one solution, maintaining most of your algorithm, is to use this sequence to set up your columns and variant arrays:

```
    Dim c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8

Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range
Dim col6 As Range
Dim col7 As Range
Dim col8 As Range
Dim out1 As Range

'Set col1 = Range("A10", Range("A10").End(xlDown))
Set col1 = Range("A10", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Set col2 = Range("B10", Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))
Set col3 = Range("C10", Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp))
Set col4 = Range("D10", Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
Set col5 = Range("E10", Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp))
Set col6 = Range("F10", Cells(Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp))
Set col7 = Range("G10", Cells(Rows.Count, "g").End(xlUp))
Set col8 = Range("H10", Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp))



c1 = col1
    If Not IsArray(c1) Then
        ReDim c1(1, 1)
        c1(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c2 = col2
    If Not IsArray(c2) Then
        ReDim c2(1, 1)
        c2(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c3 = col3
    If Not IsArray(c3) Then
        ReDim c3(1, 1)
        c3(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c4 = col4
    If Not IsArray(c4) Then
        ReDim c4(1, 1)
        c4(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c5 = col5
    If Not IsArray(c5) Then
        ReDim c5(1, 1)
        c5(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c6 = col6
    If Not IsArray(c6) Then
        ReDim c6(1, 1)
        c6(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c7 = col7
    If Not IsArray(c7) Then
        ReDim c7(1, 1)
        c7(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
c8 = col8
    If Not IsArray(c8) Then
        ReDim c8(1, 1)
        c8(1, 1) = col1.Value
    End If
```

Finally, you should, in the VB editor, set the option to require variable declaration.  This will place Option Explicit at the beginning of any new modules, and ensure you not only declare all of your variables (you did not in this code), but also will help in avoiding typos.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the problems, I applied the solution to all the columns and also declared c1 - c8 (you're right. should have done that already). however it still shows an overflow error when only one row is filled

Comment: @nkodb37 Check the dimensions of all of your c1...c8 variables when you get that error.

Comment: @nkodb37 When I apply the solution to all the columns, I do not get the overflow error if only one row is filled, in just one or in multiple columns.

Comment: i declared c1 - c8 as variants, and copied/pasted                                       If Not IsArray(c1) Then
    vTemp = c1
    ReDim c1(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    c1(1, 1) = vTemp
End If                                                                                                                      for all the columns.

Comment: **Check the dimensions of all of your c1...c8 variables when you get that error** Look in the `Locals` window.  As I indicated, I cannot reproduce that problem.

Comment: There must be something else in the rows only appear to have a single entry. Otherwise you should see c1(1 to 1, 1 to 1).  Perhaps a space?

Comment: can you post your answer and ill copy/paste it into a new excel doc?

Comment: I can post the relevant code, but since none of your c1...c8 are showing up as (1 to 1, 1 to 1), I suspect there is something unexpected about your data.

Comment: @nkodb37 I edited my answer to reflect the relevant changes I am suggesting

Comment: Thanks, it works great, only problem now is that if column1 has more than one row filled and the rest of the 7 colums only have 1 row filled, it will only generate the values for column1. are you getting the same results?

Comment: Yes, I see the same issue.  And, in the reverse, I will see `subscript out of range` on this line: `out(n, 5) = c1(j, 1)`  Examining that section of code, it would appear to be setting up for problems in a variety of circumstances, where the columns do not have equal populations.  That is a logic issue that I will leave for you to work around.